# Problema com CSS no Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```js
$(".membrosClick").click(function() {
  $(".membrosClick").css("width", "766px");
  $(this).children().fadeToggle();
  $(".listagemEsc").css("margin-left", "383px");
});
```

```html
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/EDGAR-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Edgar</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/ANTONIO-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Antônio</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Quando eu clicar na `li` ele tem que expandir ela para `width: 766px` e mandar a `div listagemEsc` para `margin-left:383px`. Ele está expandindo para 766px só que ele faz isso em todas as `li`, e não somente naquela que eu cliquei. Com isso não consegui testar o resto.

Comment: Já tentou usar `$(this).css("width", "766px");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas alterações:

- usa `$(this).css()` para só aplicares no elemento que clicaste
- usa `.next()` para ir buscar o div irmão imediatamente a seguir, em vez de chamar no seletor todos os elementos com a classe `listagemEsc`. Ou para ser mais específico `el.closest('.membrosClick').find('.listagemEsc').css("margin-left", "383px");`

Resultado final:

```
$(".membrosClick").click(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.css("width", "766px");
    el.children().fadeToggle();
    el.next().css("margin-left", "383px");
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu havia confundido as coisas antes! muito obrigado

Comment: posso incrementar a pergunta? tenho uma outra dúvida agora, mas é referente a algo que acontece depois disso.

Comment: @FelipeStoker é preferivel outra pergunta. É essa a politica do site. Mais util com problemas especificos. Não sei se é isso mas ia sugerir-te css transitions para essas mudanças de margem e width ficarem como animação.

Comment: Não é isso não, vou fazer outra pergunta então, obrigado :D