# Click em Jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery, css

Conforme essa pergunta que fiz anteriormente [e foi resolvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54148/problema-com-css-no-jquery/54150?noredirect=1#comment111089_54150) tenho uma outra questão que acontece depois disso.

```js
$(".membrosClick").click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.css("width", "766px");
  el.children().show();
});

$(".membrosFechar").click(function() {
  $(".listagemEsc").hide();
});
```

```html
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/EDGAR-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Edgar</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/ANTONIO-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Antônio</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Quando eu clico em `membrosClick` ele deixa a div com 766px. Com isso a div `listagemDesc` aparece. Isso está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém, existe uma div dentro chamada `membrosFechar`, que é um X que eu fiz para quando o usuário clicar, a div `listagemDesc` ficar com `display:hide` e acho que o ideal também é a div `membrosClick` ficar com 383px, que é o seu tamanho original antes do clique. Não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

---

### **UPDATE**

Consegui resolver, era só incluir o `event.stopPropagation();` conforme respondido no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021776/click-doesnt-work-in-jquery).

Comment: Cara, olha sempre o console de erros do browser, ele **sempre** vai te mostrar onde o erro está acontecendo.

Comment: Cara, cria a resposta para o teu problema e marca ela como certa, assim facilita quando, no futuro, alguém tiver o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.listagemEsc').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.membrosClick').width(383);
});
```

---

Atualizado:

```
$('.membrosFechar').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent('.membrosClick').width(383);
});
```

---

Atualizado:

```
$('.membrosFechar').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().css('width', '383px');
});
```

---

Se não funcionar desisto rsrs

```
$('.membrosFechar').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().css('width', '383px');
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou, tinha tentado isso antes, olha aqui http://www.musicalabertura.com.br/site/ em INTEGRANTES, quando você clica em um ele abre uma descrição do lado com a opção de fechar, era isso que eu queria.

Comment: ainda não funcionou amigo.

Comment: Eu vi que ao clicar para abrir a caixa com o texto funciona, mas depois de alguns segundos seu console fica cheio de notificações com erros, talvez esses erros possam estar lhe atrapalhando.

Comment: na verdade aqueles erros são referente a um plugin pra Youtube, que à princípio não interfere nisso, se não já daria erro antes de abrir a descrição

Comment: que estranho cara, a sua sintaxe parece estar perfeitamente correta, todavia não surte efeito no site.

Comment: valeu pelo esforço amigo. Eu pensei que o `(document).ready` estava encerrando antes, mas parece que não é isso não, infelizmente não funcionou =/

Comment: eu estava analisando, nos dois últimos updates que você fez, você informou o width, mas não informou que era do `membrosClick`

Comment: Consegui resolver, atualizei a minha pergunta! :D